# How do I run an inputted value on a imported file

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, import, flow-control

[celsius to fahrenheit file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zF8Qo.png)

[fahrenheit to celsius file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iCWs.png)

I created these two scripts (c2f.py and f2c.py) converting an input value to fahrenheit or celsius depending what scripts you use and it works fine, but i created a third tempconversion.py file and just need help with how to ask for a new input integer and ask which temperature type they would like to convert to on this file, and then import the correct conversion file in order to insert the new input on the new file. I just need to know how to properly insert the new value into the imported file and function.
the third picture showing tempconversion.py is the one that needs to be ran.
[tempconversion.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUKbo.png)

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you correctly, you are trying to pass the temperature value and type input and then run the function based on that input. In order to do that you need to pass your input as a parameter in the function

in your tempconversion.py file you should use basic input output instead of function to get input

```
import c2f, f2c

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # getting temp value in integer
    tempValue = int(input("Input a temperature to be converted : "))
    # getting type
    typeTemp = input("Convert to Fahrenheit(F) or Celcius(C)?: ")

   if (typeTemp == 'F'):
      print(c2f.c2f(tempValue))
   elif (typeTemp == 'C'):
      print(f2c.f2c(tempValue))
   else:
      print("invalid input")
```

and in f2c.py you should change it to this

```
def f2c(tempValue):
    return ((tempValue - 32 ) * 5/9)
```

because in the tempconversion we already ask the user to input the value, we dont need to make user input it again. Also we should remove the **name** == '**main**' because this file should just contain a function, we are not trying to run anything here

and in c2f.py

```
def c2f(tempValue):
   return ((tempValue * 9/5) + 32)
```